# Qual forma correta de usar form-group bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-glyphicons

Qual forma correta para usar form group ?

Eu uso da seguinte forma

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" align="center">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size:60px"></span>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-10">
            <form class="form-group" role="form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <label>Nome</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <label>Situação</label>
                                    <select class="form-control">
                                        <option>Ativa</option>
                                        <option>Inativa</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

e tirando o form-group ele funciona,

deixando ele para o input e o select ele funciona

deixando form-group para cara um dos componentes, funciona...

Qual maneira correta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A idéia é que o `.form-group` "substitua" o `.row`, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
</form>
```

> Todo conteúdo `<input>`, `<textarea>` e `<select>` desses elementos com
>   .form-control são configurados com *width: 100%*; por padrão. Coloque
>   labels e controles dentro do .form-group para obter um espaçamento
>   melhor. [Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

Comment: No exemplo que mostrei o código, se ele substitui a row, como eu dividiria as 2 colunas, conforme está no meu exemplo ?